# Search for two strings in an unsorted binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I need to show the "path" of the different nodes from a binary tree of strings. The function received two node (begin and end), assuming that they exist in the tree. The tree isn't ordered and cannot be ordered. I've thougt by using the preorder strategy.

For example if the input is monday and month the result should be:

```
monday party of month
```

Using the preorder the result is

```
monday party of friday month
```

Does anyone know to print the right path?

```
        family 
      /        \ 
    day        monday 
   /   \       /    \
  zoo  night  party  brother
 /  \  / \    /  \   /  \ 
lion        of   at      club
            /  \
        friday  month

public void fa(NodeArbre inicial,NodeArbre fi){
    if(inicial!=null){
        System.out.println(inicial._contingut+ " _ ");
        fa(inicial._esq,fi);
        fa(inicial._dret,fi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you only traverse down the tree, or can you go through parents as well (like from monday to lion)?

Comment: Okay. Then I would think of this problem as a directed graph and use [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [Kruskal's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) to traverse it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't `println` current node, since you don't know if it is on the **right** path. That means you should rather collect the visited nodes in a `list` and print it once you reach your **target node**.

Also I highly doubt that the output you've shown was produced by your program - your program doesn't check for the *target node*, it traverses the **whole** child sub-tree.

You could implement this by defining a helper recursive function which would need an additional parameter - `list` of visited nodes. For example:

```
public boolean fa(NodeArbre inicial, NodeArbre fi, List<NodeArbre> visited) {
  if (inicial == null)
    return false;
  visited.add(inicial);
  if (inicial == fi || inicial.contingut.equals(fi.contingut)) { // depends on how you want to determine node equality  
    // print list of visited?
    return true;
  }
  if (fa(inicial._esq, fi, visited))
    return true;
  else if (fa(inicial._dret, fi, visited))
    return true;
  visited.remove(inicial);
  return false;
}
```

Which you'd call from the original method `fa`

```
public void fa(NodeArbre inicial, NodeArbre fi) {
  // assign the list to a variable if you want to do something with it...
  // fa will return true if it found the path
  fa(inicial, fi, new LinkedList());
}
```

Note: I made an assumption that `_esq` points to the left child and `_dret` to the right child or vice-versa.

For the non-believers - I have tested it: http://ideone.com/U1sI7t

Comment: @gpasch Why would both children be add to `visited`? I remove the child in an incorrect path. And if already one child was on the right path, I don't check the other one.

Comment: Double equals (`==`) always scares me in comparisons in Java. Do you think it would be better to call the `equals()` method?

Comment: @callyalater no, because that's **exactly** what I want - to check if the instances are the same. Of course, it depends on how OP uses the function - if he creates a new instance of `NodeArbre` and considers them to be equal when their `_contingut` fields are equal, then it would be a good idea to compare those fields instead.

Comment: @gpasch I have added a link to ideone example.